# How to lookup for NA value in Excel?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, lookup

I have two sheets:

1. Contains form number and amount
2. Contains bill number and amount

[image: Form Table]

I tried to reconcile which bill belongs to which form using simple lookup based on the amount, ignoring duplicate amount and using the first value found.

[image: Bill Table]

After verification, this results in a static (no formula) reconciliation table, which will be updated as more form-bill get reconciled.

[image: Reconciliation Table]

I created a column to check whether a form number has been reconciled.

[image: Form Table with flag column]

Now, I want to update the bill table's lookup to exclude reconciled entries, so I put a condition to only lines entries with "#N/A".

[image: Updated Lookup]

But all of it returns N/A error!

How to fix this? I want to lookup for entries with matching amount AND has #N/A value.

Answer (score 0):

### Turn unsearchable NA to searchable string

The easiest one is to use IFNA to wrap the reconcile check column and turns it into "None" string.

[image: IFNA]

Then use "None" as your filter.

[image: Filter]

This should also works for all other errors, just replace IFNA to IFERROR.

Comment: I arrived at this answer just after I submitted the question, and wow, it only requires simple solution.